# How to show multiple calendars with one texbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to make a textbox that will select date range. It needs to display two calendars (Start Date and End Date) when it gets clicked. I am using Ajax control toolkit but it shows only one calendar and when I add two calendars with same TargetControlID, it still shows one calender.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="startDate" Text="Start Date" ReadOnly="False" EnableViewState="True" CssClass="calendar" runat="server"> 
</asp:TextBox>

  cc1:CalendarExtender EnabledOnClient="True" DefaultView="Days" PopupButtonID="calenderopener"
       ID="startDate_CalendarExtender" StartDate="Jan 15, 2014" CssClass="ajax__calendar ajax__calendar_container" EnableViewState="True"
        runat="server" BehaviorID="calendar1" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="startDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

I want to show two calendars when this textbox gets clicked.

Comment: Share you code here what you are using for this purpose.

Comment: @Umarshareef please edit your question and add the code there. Don't add the code in the comment section, it will be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This allows you to select multiple dates to single control(Textbox). If you want to use date range (only two days are selectable) then you shoud have to validate it in your code behind.
http://www.obout.com/calendar/tutorial_select_multipledates.aspx